# Image of compact set under compact set of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compactness

Taking my class in functional analysis, I've encounted  the following problem:
"Prove that the image of compact set $K\subset X$ ($X$ - normed space) under the compact set of operators $S\subset L(X)$ (with respect to operator norm) is compact".

This set is basically $\{Ax\ |\ x\in K, A\in S\}$

I tried to crack it by definition, but it gave me nothing. Then I tried to use equivalence of compactness and sequencial compactness - but it also didn't get me anywhere. I feel like I lack some trick or fact to solve this one - appreciate any hint!

Comment: Consider the linear space $V:=X\times L(X)$ equipped with the sum of he norms in $X$ and $L(X).$ The set $K\times S$ is compact in $V.$ The mapping $F:V\to X$ given by $F(x,T)=Tx$ is continuous from $V$ to $X.$ Thus $F(K\times S)$ is a compact set in $X.$ Your set is equal $F(K\times S).$

Comment: Let $(A_nx_n)$ be a sequence in your given set. Find an increasing sequence of indices $(k_n)$ such that $x_{k_n} \to x \in X$ and $A_{k_n} \to A \in L(X)$. Then $A_{k_n}x_{k_n} \to Ax$ since 
\begin{align*}
| A_{k_n}x_{k_n} -Ax| &\le |A_{k_n}x_{k_n} - A_{k_n}x| + | A_{k_n}x -Ax| 
\\
&\le \|A_{k_n}\| |x_{k_n}-x| + |x| |A_{k_n} -A| \to 0
\end{align*}